# НЕ с прилагательным ТРИВИАЛЬНЫЙ

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

Увидела в одной книге такую фразу: "Уместить всю жизнь в единую кодовую комбинацию было задачей НЕ ТРИВИАЛЬНОЙ, НО ВОЗМОЖНОЙ".

Разве можно эти два прилагательных воспринимать как противопоставление? Если противопоставления нет, НЕ со словом ТРИВИАЛЬНЫЙ должно писаться слитно. Или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написал слитно:

*Уместить всю жизнь в единую кодовую комбинацию было задачей **нетривиальной, но возможной.***

Вы правы, противопоставления нет: ***нетривиальный*** (синоним без ***не*** – сложный) и ***возможный*** – не антонимы.

> При использовании союза ***но*** соединяемые понятия не противопоставляются друг другу, так как они вполне совместимы, т. е. предмету одновременно приписываются два признака без отрицания одного из них: *река **неглубокая**, но холодная* — слитное написание отрицательной частицы.

Источник: [Частица ***не*** с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77) (справочник Розенталя).

*Рассказать детям про смерть, загробную жизнь и то, как важно помнить умерших родственников, ― задача **нетривиальная, но** далеко не новая для Disney* (Максим Сухагузов. «Тайна Коко»: образ смерти в мультфильмах Disney и Pixar (11.2017) // Афиша Daily, 2017).

***Нетривиальный, но** рельефный и связанный с предыдущим, пример...* (Александр Бикбов. Рынки культуры как рынки вкуса и признания (2004) // «Неприкосновенный запас», 15.01.2004).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Пример очень интересный )

Comment: @Татьяна  Спасибо за вопрос и принятие ответа! На стрелочки еще не забывайте нажимать :)

Comment: Нажала )) Теперь точно не забуду )